# Django model structure - model has a list of model related objects

Tags: python, django

I am wondering what would be the best structure for following situation:

```
1) There are clients who sends requests to the other clients
2) Client should be connected to the user somehow: one client = one user
3) One client can send multiple requests
4) Every client has its own clients list
```

So far, I did following:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key=True)
    my_clients = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='my_clients', symmetrical=False, blank=True)

class Request(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='receiver')
```

I was thinking to attach list of requests on the client object. Should that be made in model or it is better just to generate that list in serializer?

And can you see some pitfalls in this structure - in terms of scaling?

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1):

I can't debate on the matter of **the best structure** due to the lack of experience, but I would probably try to avoid using name such as `Client` and `Request` - too close to build-in names

Imagine you will start unit-testing and have to do the following

```
from django.test import Client
```

which, in my understanding, using your `Client` and django's `Client` will decrease readability.

Please correct me if i'm wrong.